# VSCode extension: Update TreeView item without rebuilding the tree

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my VS Code Extension, I have a TreeViewProvider that builds a pretty large tree of items.
For some of them, I just want to update certain properties like `iconPath` or `contextValue`, so they are displayed a bit differently, but no changes in the tree structure are required.

Is there any way to do this without calling `onDidChangeTreeData`, because it will call `getElement()` and `getChildren()` and rebuild the whole tree?

Comment: have you read the last paragraph on the Tree View doc page, maybe use `window.createTreeView`

Comment: @rioV8 TBH, I looked into type definitions for `createTreeView` and wasn't sure if that's what I'm looking for. What I need is the ability to get and update elements of the tree by their `id`